# Integrate Grafana with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cognito, grafana, amazon-vpc

Is there a tutorial out there that describes how to integrate Grafana (running in an EC2 instance) with AWS Cognito for authentification? 
Or could somebody tell me how to do it? I'm relatively new to AWS and also Grafana.

We use Grafana with ElasticSearch.

Or would it be better to put Grafana and Elasticsearch in a VPC and communicate via API Gateway and Lambda with Grafana?

Best regards